# How to join two JSONB columns in a table?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to ask how to join two JSONB columns in a table. I'm currently reading on how to use lateral joins but can't seem to make them work.

My Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    questions JSONB,
    answers JSONB
);

INSERT INTO quiz(questions, answers)
VALUES
('{"Q1": "Question 1",
"Q2": "Question 2",
"Q3": "Questiuon 3"}',


'{"Q1": "Answer 1",
"Q2": "Answer 2",
"Q3": "Answer 3"}');
```

Expected output:

```
------------ +-----------
| questions  |  answers |
-------------------------
| Question 1 | Answer 1 |
| Question 2 | Answer 2 |
| Question 3 | Answer 3 |
-------------+-----------
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kMYPHTAkAgS6EgLdW3sjQ8/0)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=96b6fc4c27eeedf2157b7505723c5efa)

You could expand both JSON columns separately using `jsonb_each_text()`, which returns two columns (`key` and `value`), and join the results afterwards:

```
SELECT
    q.value as question,
    a.value as answer
FROM (
    SELECT
        questions.key,
        questions.value
    FROM quiz,
        jsonb_each_text(questions) as questions
) q 
JOIN (
    SELECT
        answers.key,
        answers.value
    FROM quiz,
        jsonb_each_text(answers) as answers
) a ON a.key = q.key
```

---

Supposing you have always the same keys in `questions` and `answers`, you could do this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=09cdd4ead91d4ec007268f6186e5a3d0)

```
SELECT
    questions ->> key,
    answers ->> key
FROM quiz,
    jsonb_object_keys(questions) as key
```

Retrieving the `keys` from one column and use them to fetch the values from both.